# Bridging a VM to access my LAN

Tags: linux, bridge

I've been trying to set up a bridge connection for a while now and I can't seem to get it to work the way I want it to.

I'm using a dell poweredge t140 with kali installed. I installed VirtManager with KVM/QEMU. I wanted to run two vms, one ubuntu server with apache, and another CentOS or OpenSUSE server doing dns.

I get the bridge setup and I can ping the bridge from outside network, but I can't ping the VMs. I give them their static IP address and they can all ping within the vnet, but not out into the LAN. I have been reading up on bridges for a bit and I thought I was getting the hand of it, but I can't seem to get around this problem and I haven't found a fix or a tutorial that works. I'll put some addressing information below in case it helps

#### Network 1

- Router 1

  - Int G0/0/1 192.168.10.97/30 Up
  - Int G0/0/0 192.168.10.1/26 Up
  - Switch 1

    - Int G0/1 Up

      - Router 1
    - Int Fa0/1 Up

      - Chromebook-1-1 192.168.10.8 (DHCP)
    - Int G0/2

      - PC1 (Host of VMs) (All Static)

        - eth1 10.0.2.10 Up (Schools LAN so that I can use the internet)
        - br0 192.168.10.3 Up

          - eth0 master br0 Up (LAN lab)
          - vnet0 192.168.10.4 Up (Apache server)
          - vnet1 192.168.10.5 Up (DNS server) (Not started yet)

#### Network 2

- Router 2

  - Int G0/0/1 192.168.10.98/30 Up
  - Int G0/0/0 192.168.10.65/27 Up

    - Switch 2

      - Int G0/1 Up

        - Router-2
      - Int Fa0/1

        - Chromebook-2-1 192.168.10.71/28

If any other information is needed I can provide while I'm at school.

This is all Cisco equipment. Routers are Cisco 4300 series and Switches are Cisco Catalyst 2960+.

Comment: Please edit your question to add info on what VM software you are using. VirtualBox? VMWare Fusion? Parallels? Something else?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question, the solution lies primarly in how you connect your virtual network to the hosts physical network, so it is critical we know what your virtualization product is, as Giacomo1984 has asked. its likely you don't need a host bridge at all.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the suggestions, i'll add more information.

Comment: use oracle virtualbox with ``bridged adapter''

Comment: "vnet0 192.168.10.4 Up " : this IP address should appear only in the VM. If it appears on the Kali host, that's a misconfiguration: a bridge *port* must not be given an IP address. Please clarify (I might just have read it wrong).